# Как подлючиться к Wifi?

Tags: python, wifi

Как при помощи python.
Подлючится к Wifi на любой операционной системе. Зная пароль, название интернета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение для linux/windows - pywifi
Пример кода:

```
import pywifi

profile = pywifi.Profile()
profile.ssid = 'testap' #ssid сети
profile.auth = pywifi.const.AUTH_ALG_OPEN #алгоритм аутентификации сети
profile.akm.append(pywifi.const.AKM_TYPE_WPA2PSK) #тип кей-менеджмента сети
profile.cipher = pywifi.const.CIPHER_TYPE_CCMP #тип шифрования сети
profile.key = '12345678' #пароль сети

wifi = pywifi.PyWiFi()
iface = wifi.interfaces()[0]
profile = iface.add_network_profile(profile)
iface.connect(profile)
```

А вот ссылочка на [документацию](https://github.com/awkman/pywifi/blob/master/DOC.md)

Comment: Что делать если оно только отключается от интернета. Но никак его не подключает

Comment: Что делать если оно только отключается от интернета. Но никак его не подключает

Comment: Вы точно к нужной сети подключаетесь?